# how to drag and drop a div into another div and after dragging the div do not move using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, drag-and-drop

How to drag and drop a div into another div and after dragging the div do not move using jQuery.

Comment: What you have tried so far ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by do not move, you mean, don't move the original item, then with a combination of dragable with revert set to true, and dropable

http://jqueryui.com/droppable/#revert

```
$(function() {
    $( "#draggable" ).draggable({ revert: "valid" });
    $( "#droppable" ).droppable();
  });
```